# How to fix soft 404 in an Ajax Driven website?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-status-code-404

I have a website that first loads the page with a 200 response. Once the page is loaded, Data is populated using an ajax call.

But sometimes for some urls, there is no data and the ajax call returns 404 code and I display 'No results found' on my page.
But this has raised lot many soft 404 errors on my website.
Google crawler get 200 status code but the webpage says 'No results found'.
I want to fix these errors as it has affected the SEO of the site.
A google search says,

1) hardcode status code to 404. But I have no idea how this can be done once the page is loaded as the page doesn't know until the ajax call returns the status.

2) fix the content,

3) 301 to some other page. This has problems similar to 1).

How can these errors be fixed for these pages ?

Answer (score -1):

To fix the errors displayed by the crawler you should setup a robots.txt to ignore the urls you don't want displayed.

See here for more info: [robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)